# How can I specify a limit to a query and to be pageable

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-rest

I would like my Rest API to retrieve for me the X last records in a mongo database with pagination. So that when a user wants the 1000 last records, he will only get the first 100 records on the first page, etc ...
But it doesn't work that way.

I want the url to look like that :
http://localhost/api/devices/{device}/topics/{topic}/last/{limit}

and not like :
http://localhost/api/devices/{device}/topics/{topic}/last?size={limit}

```
@Override
public Page<DeviceData> findFirstXByDeviceAndTopicOrderByDateDesc(String device, String topic, int x, Pageable pageable) {
    Query query = new Query(Criteria.where(DEVICE_KEY).is(device).and(TOPIC_KEY).is(topic));
    query.with(new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, DATE_KEY));
    query.limit(x);
    query.with(pageable);

    List<DeviceData> list = mongoTemplate.find(query, DeviceData.class);
    Page<DeviceData> page = new PageImpl<DeviceData>(list);

    return page;
}
```

I get all the records with pagination...

How can I limit the results and hava pagination based on that result.

Comment: And what is wrong with that URL? If you want something else use URL rewriting to convert the first to the second url.